# Using AJAX to send and receive info from a server

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm working on a page that is supposed to interact with the server via AJAX, but my experience with AJAX is extremely limited. Here's how the page is supposed to work.

When the button is clicked, if the "test" radio button is clicked, just display a pop up saying the input was valid.
When the button is clicked, if the "live" radio button is clicked, the program is supposed to send a request to the server using the URL "http://cs.sfasu.edu/rball/351/exam2.php" with the contents of the input box being the value for the "name" parameter.
The page will then send back a JSON object that I need to parse into a regular variable.

I'll leave the rest of the JSON stuff alone since that's not what I asked.

So far I have the design of the page done, but like I said I don't really know what I'm doing with the AJAX stuff. I have some code written for it, but not sure that it's right.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>anner, Taylor</title>

        <style type = "text/css">
            canvas {
                border: 2px solid black;
            }
        </style>

        <script type = "text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                var TTcanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                var TTcontext = TTcanvas.getContext("2d");

                TTcontext.strokeStyle = "red";
                TTcontext.fillStyle = "red";
                TTcontext.fillRect(250,50,100,100);
                TTcontext.stroke();

                TTcontext.beginPath();
                TTcontext.moveTo(600, 0);
                TTcontext.lineTo(0, 200);
                TTcontext.lineWidth = 5;
                TTcontext.strokeStyle = "black";
                TTcontext.stroke();

            }

            function validate() {
                var TTinput = document.getElementById("3letters").value;

                if(TTinput.length < 3 || TTinput.length > 3) {
                    alert("Please enter 3 letters");
                }

                var TTtest = document.getElementById("test");
                var TTlive = document.getElementById("live");

                if(TTtest.checked == true) {
                    alert("Input is valid");
                }
                else if(TTlive.checked == true) {
                    return ajaxStuff();
                }
            }

            function ajaxStuff() {
                var TTrequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                TTrequest.open("GET", "http://cs.sfasu.edu/rball/351/exam2.php?name=TTinput.value", true);
                TTrequest.send();
                var TTresponse = TTrequest.responseText;
                TTrequest.onreadystatechange=function() {
                            if(TTrequest.readyState==4 && TTrequest.status==200) {
                                           document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML.TTresponse;
                            }
                        }
            }       
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Tanner, Taylor</h1>

        <canvas id = "myCanvas" width = "600" height = "200"></canvas> <br>

        <form>
            Enter 3 letters: <input type="text" id="3letters"> <br>
            <input type = "radio" id = "test" value = "test">Test
            <input type = "radio" id = "live" value = "live">Live <br>
            <input type = "button" id = "check" value = "Send" onclick="validate()">
        </form>

        <div id="myDiv">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is a link to my page on our server:

```
cs.sfasu.edu/cs351121/exam2.html
```

Also, I know it says exam, but this is actually just a review we were given for the actual exam that's next week. I'm just trying to figure out how this works but don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: your calling the .open twice which results to it to an infinite loop.

Comment: Just noticed that, about to edit the post now with corrected code. Not getting the error anymore, but not getting anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is. The code is correct

Ok now i get the problem. You are calling the request variable outside the scope. You are declaring the request variable inside your ajaxStuff function so its only accessible in that area. Thats why it is undefined. Try this:

```
 function ajaxStuff() {
                        var TTrequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                TTrequest.open("GET", "http://cs.sfasu.edu/rball/351/exam2.php?name=TTinput.value", true);
                        TTrequest.send();

                TTrequest.onreadystatechange=function() {
                            if(TTrequest.readyState==4 && TTrequest.status==200) {
                                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=TTrequest.responseText;
                            }
                        }
            }
```

to get the result just do this

```
TTrequest.send();
var response=TTrequest.responseText;
```

Comment: I think one of my problems is my functions. I keep getting an error that says "TTrequest is not defined" at the "TTrequest.onreadystatechange = function() {" part of the code. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: oh did not catch that. Ofcourse it is not defined since you defined the variable inside your function then accessed out side of it. see my edited code above

Comment: Well, that fixed that, but now I'm getting all these "NS_ERROR_FAILURE:" Messages, with one saying "Too much Recursion" thrown in there every now again. The web console basically looks like the console does in a compiler when you've written an endless loop...

Comment: Oops did not escape the function properly. Updated my answer to add the closing bracket for the onready function. Please try again.

Comment: Oh I caught that, but this latest thing happened after I added the closing bracket.

Comment: The line it gives as a reference for the error is line 58 which is the one with "TTrequest.send();" Don't know if that helps or not.

Comment: post your updated code please. you did see that i updated my answer to remove the calling of .send again right?

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check if it works now. That should finally do it. Dont forget to accept this as answer if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I know, I do not see the jQuery tag, but consider it if there are no framework restrictions.

Example:

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $.ajax({url:"demo_test.txt",success:function(result){
     $("#div1").html(result);
   }});
 });
```